# How can I pass a line of code in textInput in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to pass a line of code in textInput function, like suppose I write `list(a = c("b", "c"))` in textInput. But textInput would take it as a character string.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` and `parse` from base R. Please note that it can be dangerous to evaluate user defined code, so think twice.

```
string <- 'list(a = c("b", "c"))'
eval(parse(text = string))
#$a
#[1] "b" "c"
```